# XAML Property elements

Tags: c#, xaml

For a project I am using XAML. I have devided my screen in different parts. The moment when I add a button, I get an error.

The error:

> 'property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content'

The code I am using for the button where the error has been found:

```
<Button x:Name="cntButton" Content="Connect" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Click="cntButton_Click" />
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I have to solve it?

The rest of the code:

```
<Window x:Class="Pesten.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Image Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Stretch="Fill" Source="pestenbg.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button x:Name="cntButton" Content="Connect" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Click="cntButton_Click" />

</Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the XAML file?

Comment: The Button element itself seems fine. Could you post more of the XAML? Perhaps the whole of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Error: Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content. They must be before or after the content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524787/wpf-error-property-elements-cannot-be-in-the-middle-of-an-elements-content-th)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've defined an image in the grid before the grid properties. Move this to after the row and column definitions.

Comment: Glad to help. Tick to accept the answer and then we're all happy :-)

Comment: I will but have to wait for the delay of 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding `Button` control in the wrong place of parent control:

[Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907325%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content. **They must be before or after the content.** This error is occurs when you attempt to use property-element syntax within an element's content.

Move `Image` after `ColumnDefinitions` and before `Button`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Stretch="Fill" Source="pestenbg.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/> 
    <Button x:Name="cntButton" Content="Connect" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Click="cntButton_Click" />

</Grid>
```

or move both `Image` and `Button` above column/row definition but you cannot split it

Answer (score 1):

Put the column and row definitions directly after the opening  tag. All content should follow that (i.e. the  and  the  ).