# WPF Error: Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content. They must be before or after the content

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `MergedDictionaries` and `DateTemplate` inside a `ResourceDictionary` and everything was fine until I added a `Converter`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTry">

    <local:IsEnabledConverter x:Key="isEnabled"/>  <===== causes problem

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="fileinfoTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:MyFileInfo}">
        ... template stuff
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Adding the `Converter` line causes this error at the line of `DataTemplate`:

```
Property elements cannot be in the middle of an element's content. They must be before or after the content.
```

Why is causing this error?

Note that the code compiles and the Converter works fine if I comment out the `MergedDictionaries`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error tells you the issue:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTry">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

   <!-- Move this here -->
   <local:IsEnabledConverter x:Key="isEnabled"/>

   <DataTemplate x:Key="fileinfoTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:MyFileInfo}">
        ... template stuff
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

You are trying to put content before setting properties on the resource dictionary. The error says "property elements" (e.g. `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`) cannot be in the middle of an elements "content" (e.g. your datatemplate/converters etc)

Anything that has a dot `.` must appear at the top of an element as you are essentially setting properties in the XAML. Anything that doesn't have a `.` is content and must appear below any property setters.

**Note:** this also works the other way round, properties can also be below all the content if you prefer it that way round

Comment: Why does it have to be at the top? I have never found the answer for the "Why". Why does it also work when it's at the bottom?

Comment: It's just a design choice. XAML is parsed into a data structure and my guess is that each element sets a property on the resulting object that represents it. It's also probably that resource dictionaries must be specified ahead of the content being constructed since they could be used in the XAML, I think the parser is probably smart enough to pick up certain things as a priority.

Comment: ```"It's also probably that resource dictionaries must be specified ahead of the content being constructed since they could be used in the XAML,"```
I don't think that's 100% true. When you set it at the bottom, you can still use it at the top, assuming that it constructs the XAML from top to bottom.

Comment: @Sound when I said that I didn't mean that they needed to be above the content in the XAML, just that they needed to be parsed/ready to use before the content is constructed - that's what I meant by the parser is smart enough to pick things up as a priority. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288606/how-does-a-xaml-parser-identify-namescopes this seems to suggest resource dictionaries are treated as a special case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528909/how-is-xaml-interpreted-and-executed-at-runtime/20529118 also shows how XAML constructs and sets properties.

Comment: Yeah, anything that has a dot ```.``` has to either be at the top of everything, or at the bottom of everything in XAML. Just to confirm, there's no other reason for this other than it's a design choice and how it constructs XAML in the background?

Comment: Well, dotted things are attached properties - so I think that's probably irrelevant (you can have `<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">` in the middle of content for example), but certainly mixing things like resource dictionaries (which are integral to how the framework locates stuff) with content is probably not worth supporting.

Comment: Yeah, I meant dotted things like properties/dependencyproperties, not attached properties. 
```<Grid.BackGround....``` for example

Comment: Yes, in that case - it's just a hard-fast rule that that stuff is setting up the "owner" by decking out properties with values and I believe this happens just after the constructor, but the `Content` property on a control is a special case and is probably parsed/dealt with in a certain way.

Comment: What do you mean by the Content property?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content?view=net-5.0 it's the default property you are setting when putting stuff in the middle of the XAML in 
most controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same error if the there is incorrect XAML in file which may not be obvious (the error message is not too specfic).

For example the following will produce this error:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1"> <!-- delete starting this line to fix -->
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        </Grid> <!-- delete ending this line to fix -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Button1"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button2"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Button3"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

The fix is to delete the blocked marked in the XAML above.