# How does a XAML parser identify NameScopes?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, parsing

In the context of XAML parsing, I would like to know how does the parser know when a type defines a NameScope.

Does it rely entirely on the INameScope interface, checking `instance is INameScope`?

Does it rely on the boolean property XamlType.IsNameScope?

Is it a mix of both?

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarified what you mean by "_the parser_". As far as I know _XAML_ is a language and it does not imply usage of any particular parser. I can only guess you're referring to the one used by _WPF_ framework, but even that begs for at least specifying its version. Otherwise, if it isn't a parser specific question, the answer would be "it depends on the implementation".

Answer (score 6):

The Microsoft documentation has some good information on this:

> By default when used by .NET Framework XAML Services API, **the primary XAML namescope is defined at the XAML root element** of a single XAML production, and encompasses the elements that are contained in that XAML production.

The takeaway here is that the root element in any Xaml document has a name scope created for it.  This happens **regardless** of whether the element implements `INameScope` (and, in fact, no core UI elements do).

> Additional discrete XAML namescopes that might occur within a single XAML production can be defined by frameworks to address specific scenarios. For example, **in WPF, new XAML namescopes are defined and created by any template** that is also defined on that XAML production. For more information about XAML namescopes (written for WPF but relevant for many XAML namescope concepts), see [WPF XAML Namescopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes).

In addition to the name scope created for the root element, name scopes are implicitly created for any template defined within a Xaml production.    This should not be surprising, as `FrameworkTemplate` implements `INameScope`, and thus so do `DataTemplate` and `ControlTemplate`.  Name scopes are also created for `Style` elements.

You may notice that `ResourceDictionary` also implements `INameScope`, but it is a bit of an edge case: names of objects in a resource dictionary are not *actually* registered in any runtime name scope.  If you look at the implementation, you will see that its `INameScope` methods either throw a `NotSupportedException`, do nothing, or return `null`.  This design keeps the names nicely contained.  They are prevented from being registered in any parent scope, while making them available for limited purposes like using an `ElementName` reference on a `Binding`.  To reiterate, resource dictionaries as name scopes are an edge case that, practically speaking, you should never have to think about.

Beyond the implicitly created scopes outlined above, a new name scope is created for the Xaml parser frame of any object creation node where the created object implements `INameScope`.  As with all name scopes, registered names must be unique *within that scope*; they may, however, collide with names in other names scopes further up the stack.

When materializing an object from Xaml, the `XamlObjectWriter` resolve names by walking up the stack looking for frames with name scopes, stopping once it finds a scope containing the desired name.  This would happen, for example, when evaluating a deferred reference from an `x:Reference` directive.

> Does it rely entirely on the `INameScope` interface, checking `instance is INameScope`?
>   Does it rely on the `boolean` property `XamlType.IsNameScope`?

Generally the latter, but that flag is set by determining whether a type is assignable to the Xaml `INameScope` type, which maps to `System.Windows.Markup.INameScope`.  It does not check the runtime instance, but rather the `XamlType` of the corresponding object creation node.  Conceptually, the check is similar to `typeof(INameScope).IsAssignableFrom(instanceType)`.

Although you didn't ask it, I'd like to address one final point for the sake of completeness:

> When is an object registered in a name scope?

This happens under two conditions:

1. You explicitly set the `x:Name` pseudo-property on a Xaml element;
2. You set a property like `FrameworkElement.Name`, which is defined as a *runtime name property*.

Types like `FrameworkElement` have their own `Name` property, and rather than forcing developers to specify `Name` and `x:Name` separately, they provided a way to map the CLR property to `x:Name`.  If you look at the sources for `FrameworkElement`, you will see a `[RuntimeNameProperty("Name")]` attribute.  This tells the Xaml infrastructure that the `Name` property on a any `FrameworkElement` corresponds to `x:Name`, and setting one should result in the other being set as well.  Note that the runtime name property can have any valid name; it needn't be called `Name`.